# How to retrieve all the Web Application URLs using WSS object model

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I was able to retrieve all the web application names within a farm using object model.
But I could not find a way to display all the web application URLs within a farm.

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webapplication urls are bound to the Zones used by the webapplication (i.e. the Default, Internet and Intranet zones), find them using the `SPWebApplication.AlternateUrls` property. ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.alternateurls.aspx))

Comment: Hi Colin

Thanks for the response. It helped me alot.

Thanks

Carol

Answer (score 1):

I take it you probably really want all site collection URLs on all web applications. Here's a short powershell script I wrote - you should be able to infer the C# OM from this:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.sharepoint") > $null

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::local.services | `
    where-object {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService] } | `
    select -expand webapplications | select -expand sites | `
    select url, zone, owner, rootweb | format-table -auto
```

Hope this helps,

-Oisin

Comment: I just want to populate all the Web Application URLs using WSS object model.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. Refer the link below:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ede30d20-d471-4722-8f3a-cf00f58cbfb0